# How do I delete the year within the column in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I delete the year within the columnn?
For example the column is Author:

```
John Smith (1999-2000)
Bobby Bob (8th Century AD)
Robert Rob (712-800)
```

I would like to delete everything within the `()` and just only display the authors name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
UPDATE authors
SET authorsname = TRIM(LEFT(authorsname, INSTR(authorsname, '(') - 1))
WHERE authorsname LIKE '%(%'
```

Which will replace each names that contains an opening bracket with the left part (`LEFT`) of it until the first opening bracket (`INSTR`), then removing blank spaces before and after the result (`TRIM`)

Comment: im sorry im confuse with the table name and name. can you make it more specific. my table name is authors and the column name is authorsname and as mention above to delete the everything within ()

Comment: @merrill Sorry I couldn't get to a computer earlier :)